# iBeacon: Trying to track more zones than we have room for

Tags: ibeacon

I have this message in the console, but i have checked with locationManager.monitoredRegions and locationManager.rangedRegions that my application does not monitor to much region...
How to know the total number of monitored region by the smartphone (and not by the current locationManager) ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a system-wide list of beacon regions that your iOS device is monitoring. You're limited to your app's sandbox.

For the case of reaching the 20 region limit for your app, you'll have to rely on the `CLLocationManager.monitoredRegions` property to smartly remove and add iBeacon regions that are relevant to the current user.

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the API, this might be what you are looking for:
[-[CLLocationManager monitoredRegions]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/monitoredRegions)

`-[CLLocationManager monitoredRegions]`returns the list of all regions monitored.
Beacons are special regions based on Bluetooth low energy, you can fetch them with that property.

If you want to *know the total number of monitored region by the smartphone*, use `[[CLLocationManager monitoredRegions] count]` to get the total number of monitored regions of every location manager.

You can check if you are monitoring in a certain region by comparing their 
`identifier`. You can't monitor several regions with the same identifier, if you start monitoring a region with a identifier that already exists, it replaces the region.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is not a link answer, the link is only to prove that the property exists. It's a link to the online iOS API doc, I don't think it will become invalid for a while or without redirection. At least I wrote the method he must use, there's no need to visit the link. I slightly improve my answer to use more characters and clarify what is a region/a beacon.

Comment: monitoredRegions will give you current app's regions, not a system-wide list